# Camelot python how add file path

Tags: odoo-12, python-camelot

In `camelot` Python accepts only the current directory. If adding the file temporary it's not accepted. Is there any solution for this?

I got following error:

```
File "/home/arun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1689, in read
stream.seek(-1, 2)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

How to add the correct path? Please explain this with an example: it will be helpful to me.

```
 def generate_pdf_csv(self):
        file_name = self.pdf_name
        attachment_dict = {
                            'name': file_name,
                            'datas': self.file_upload_pdf,
                            'datas_fname': file_name,
                            'res_model': self._name,
                            'res_id': self.id,
                            'type': 'binary',
                        }
        attachment_id = 
        self.env['ir.attachment'].sudo().create(attachment_dict)
        temp_dir = tempfile.gettempdir()
        temp_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, file_name)
        pdf_file = temp_path
        tables = camelot.read_pdf(pdf_file, pages='all')
        csv_file = 'FOLLL123.csv'
        tables.export(csv_file, f='csv', compress=True)
        tables[0].to_csv(csv_file)
```

Comment: Please explain better and provide an example.